# Format strings in fscanf

Tags: c, string, format, scanf

I would like to use fscanf to read from a file that's a list of numbers (the length is arbitrary)

```
42
20
8
5
0
```

However, I am not sure how to construct a format string that reads an arbitrary number of values like this.

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
while(fscanf(fp,"%d",&number) == 1)  
{  
       printf("%d",number);  
}
```

`fscanf` returns the number of items read and returns EOF on end of file